# Django - Template form date filtering a field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-template-filters

### View

```
def editor(request):
    form = SessionForm(initial={
        'end_time': datetime.datetime.now(),
    })

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SessionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render_to_response('planner/editor.html',
        {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

This view displays the form and re-displays it on error, so there are 2 cases:

1. initialized
2. on error

In the template, I'm trying to display the field `end_time` with a date filter

### Test 1

```
  <div>End value: {{ form.end_time.value }}</div>
  <div>End value filtered: {{ form.end_time.value|date:"Y-m-d" }}</div>
```

Case 1 (initialized)

> End value: 2012-04-23 12:30:00
>   End value filtered: 2012-04-23

Case 2 (on error)

> End value: 2012-04-23 12:30:00
>   End value filtered:

### Test 2

Now let's try to remove the `.value` of `end_time`

```
  <div>End value: {{ form.end_time.value }}</div>
  <div>End value filtered: {{ form.end_time|date:"Y-m-d" }}</div>
```

Case 1 (initialized)

> End value: 2012-04-23 12:30:00
>   End value filtered:

Case 2 (on error)

> End value: 2012-04-23 12:30:00
>   End value filtered: 2012-04-23

As you can see it's doing the inverse.
How can this be explained ?

Comment: Why do you continually renew a question by deleting and creating instead of updating?

Comment: Form fields are not model fields, so I don't know why `{{ form.field }}` would give you a DateTime and not a Field instance (maybe this is a new feature?) but is `end_time` actually shown in the form as an input box? This calls for `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the view code and playing around with the form fields, request.POST, etc. to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @okm The last question I deleted was because I had accidentally submitted the form half filled by pressing Enter from the input tag and got neged & close voted. Before it was because the question was originally badly asked and I estimated it no longer useful for anybody.

Comment: Thank you Yuji, I'm going to try `pdb`

Comment: @YujiTomita In both cases (initialized & onerror) `form['start_time'].value` seems to be the same time of object: `<bound method BoundField.value of <django.forms.forms.BoundField object at 0x.....>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
{{ form.instance.end_time|date:"Y-m-d" }}
```

Instead of

```
{{ form.end_time|date:"Y-m-d" }}
```

Seems to works in both cases